# subprocess.Popen not parsing arguments correctly

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I have been playing around with `subprocess.Popen` to execute a program for a little bit but have not been able to come up with the correct way to pass the arguments.

Here is a simplified code snippet that should execute my program:

```
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('dflat --portfolio jumpy --seed 1 --tables -n semi --elimination min-degree -e edge --default-join -p ../test_encodings/exchange.lp'))
```

The output of `shlex.split(...)`:

```
['dflat', '--portfolio', 'jumpy', '--seed', '1', '--tables', '-n', 'semi', '--elimination', 'min-degree', '-e', 'edge', '--default-join', '-p', '../test_encodings/exchange.lp']
```

However the called program fails telling me that I need to provide a program (`-p` option) which I did as you can see above.

Running the command from shell works perfectly fine though.

Comment: This is a place where a SSCCE would be invaluable. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: According to comments, this issue is not reproducible. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducer other people could run (as opposed to something requiring the non-standard `dflat` program).

In general, the approach you post should work. That said, it's more conventional, less error-prone, and arguably more readable to just split the array yourself.

```
subprocess.Popen([
    'dflat',
    '--portfolio', 'jumpy',
    '--seed', '1',
    '--tables',
    '-n', 'semi',
    '--elimination', 'min-degree',
    '-e', 'edge',
    '--default-join',
    '-p', '../test_encodings/exchange.lp'])
```

Doing this by hand means that you can put each option which itself takes an argument on a line with that argument, increasing readability. This also means you avoid quoting issues if your arguments contain literal spaces, quotation marks, etc. Using `shlex.split()` gives you the a subset of the problems you'd have if you just passed the literal string as the first argument and used `shell=True` -- albeit somewhat less so, as you don't need to worry about content being misinterpreted as redirection characters, piping, compound commands, command indirection, &c.

Comment: Agreed. Then you could also play around with the arguments and see if dflat expects -p to be lumped together with the file argument in the same string or something odd like that.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked, I don't have any problems with any other programs so it seems to be the dflat program that causes the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

The command in your question seems correct. Make sure that your code uses the exactly the same code without any changes.

My guess is that `--default-join` option eats `-p` argument. You could test it by moving `--default-join` at the end of the command.

Also make sure that you start the script from the correct directory. `-p` value is a relative path. Check whether the file is accessible.

Comment: Hi thanks,it seems to be a problem with dflat, the paths were absolute I just changed them to relative since I wanted to spare you the hassle of going through my complete working tree.